# WPF Multiple windows with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

What is the common\best practice when working with multiple windows with MVVM? 
I have one window with a button, when clicking on the button I want to open a second window and close the first window. How can I do that with MVVM? should I have a MainViewModel instance for each window? or should I have only one instance of the MainViewModel that all the windows will use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) suggest a concept called [Conductors](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition) that handles this situation pretty well.

you can manage the lifetime of a screen or multiple screens by making your `MainViewModel` inherit from `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive` or `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` depending how many active windows can be shown at once.

It hold `Items` which is the currently conducted items and provides `OnActivate` and `OnDeactive` methods where you can implement your on activation and deactivation logic.

This is a very strong framework, but it will require you to incorporate Caliburn.Micro in your project and bootstrapping it which may be kind of a hassle if you are working with a different MVVM framework. However you can still implement this concept or look for similar implementations in other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Frame" and "Pages" inside it. I think that is the best solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

1. open a new View by using the code-behind (I do not like this solution, since it is not very MVVM compliant)
2. you can use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

I do not know if you are using a specific MVVM framework (like Caliburn.Micro, MVVM-light and so on), so if you are looking for a generic solution which uses Dependency Injection, you can find tons of good articles.

I suggest you to read these ones:

1. [WPF Master Details MVVM Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application)
2. [Showing Dialogs When Using the MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern)
3. [Cinch V2: Version 2 of my Cinch MVVM framework: Part 1 of n](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87541/CinchV-Version-of-my-Cinch-MVVM-framework-part#MefedMVMM) - just the "MEFedMVVM and ViewModel/Service Resolution" chapter